# Why fitted values with function in R get different values from the ideal?

Tags: r, function, regression

When testing a function to calculate some regression values, I noticed that the values predicted by `function` are not the same as they should be. When I perform the fit of the values in another way, I get the correct values.

- My regression equation (A=x1; B=x2):

[image]

**How do I actually write the `f` function to calculate the values correctly?**

My Code for the `function`:

```
A = seq(5, 8, 0.2)
B = seq(30, 70, length.out = length(A))

f <- function(A,B) 281.5786111-39.2014931*A-2.9013646*B+0.5666979*A*B

dadosz <- list(A = A, B = B)
gridz <- expand.grid(dadosz)
gridz[, "fit"] <- f(A, B)

library(lattice)
wireframe(fit ~ A * B, data = gridz,
      panel.aspect = 0.5,
      zoom = 0.8,
      screen = list(z = 215, x = -60),
      scales=list(arrows = FALSE),
      drape = TRUE, 
      col.regions = heat.colors(100, alpha = 1))
```

[image]

Using package and data manipulation to do the same job, but with the goal of making the code reproducible. Note that the values fitted here are correct.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

term <- c("(Intercept)", "A", "B", "A:B")
estimate <- c(281.5786111, -39.2014931, -2.9013646, 0.5666979)
std.error <- c(58.35909505, 7.47207607, 0.63829627, 0.05755324)
statistic <- c(4.824931, -5.246399, -4.545483, 9.846500)
p.value <- c(1.583042e-04, 6.565454e-05, 2.865084e-04, 1.941398e-08)

coe <- data.frame(term, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value)

exp <- expand.grid(A = A, B = B) %>% 
  mutate(bo = as.numeric(1)) %>% 
  mutate(ult = A*B) %>% 
  select(bo, A, B, ult) %>% 
  as.matrix()

m_beta <- coe$estimate
reg <- t(m_beta %*% t(exp)) 
exp <- cbind(exp, reg) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rename(reg = V5)

wireframe(reg ~ A * B, data = exp,
      panel.aspect = 0.5,
      zoom = 0.8,
      screen = list(z = 310, x = -70),
      scales=list(arrows = FALSE),
      drape = TRUE, 
      col.regions = heat.colors(100, alpha = 1))
```

[image]

As I was having doubts, I tested it in Excel and on an [internet site](https://www.math.uri.edu/~bkaskosz/flashmo/graph3d/), and checked again that the error is in `function`.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we look at the lines

```
dadosz <- list(A = A, B = B)
gridz <- expand.grid(dadosz)
gridz[, "fit"] <- f(A, B)
```

You can see that use used `expand.grid` to create all the combinations of `A` and `B`, but you didn't use those values when calling `f()`, instead you used the original values of `A` and `B`. You should have done

```
gridz[, "fit"] <- f(gridz$A, gridz$B)
```

This gives the plot

[image]